# NSGregorianCalendar deprecated

Tags: objective-c, xcode, nscalendar

I have a problem. I wanted to know how to remove Warning ?
thanks
`

```
NSDate *fireDate = [picker_date date];

NSCalendar *gregorian = [[NSCalendar alloc] initWithCalendarIdentifier:NSGregorianCalendar];
NSDateComponents *offsetComponents = [[NSDateComponents alloc] init];
[offsetComponents setMinute:-10];
NSDate *heure_notification = [gregorian dateByAddingComponents:offsetComponents toDate:fireDate options:0];


UILocalNotification *local_rappel_notification = [[UILocalNotification alloc]init];
local_rappel_notification.fireDate = heure_notification;
local_rappel_notification.alertBody = @"VOUS AVEZ  UN VOL MAINTENANT DANS 10 MIN!!";
local_rappel_notification.timeZone = [NSTimeZone defaultTimeZone];
local_rappel_notification.soundName = UILocalNotificationDefaultSoundName;
local_rappel_notification.applicationIconBadgeNumber = [[UIApplication sharedApplication] applicationIconBadgeNumber] + 1;

[[UIApplication sharedApplication ]scheduleLocalNotification:local_rappel_notification];
```

}`[image: warnig photo]

Comment: Read the documentation and the description in the error.

Answer (score 14, accepted):

If you read the error message (make the view wider) you will see that `NSGregorianCalendar` is now replaced with `NSCalendarIdentifierGregorian` since iOS 8.

So use `NSCalendarIdentifierGregorian`